# Use Eventbrite API to create ticket order on 3rd party website

Tags: eventbrite

Here's my flow - is this possible with eventbrite APIs? if yes, which ones specifically? I've tried looking through current listed apis and don't see how I can create the order and then pass it on to the eventbrite site for processing the order.
I am trying to find an API whereby I would pass-in discount code along with #of tickets and eventID from my website to eventbrite site.  Is there a good example for this?
The workflow that I want to implement is:-

**Step 1** On My Website, there is eventbrite Ticket Widget button along with Ticket Previews (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/widgets/#button) on the event page

**Step 2**: Clicks on Buy Tickets/Register/ buttons (from the widget)

**Step 3**: redirect to eventbrite website with eventID, user-elgible-discount-code, #of-tickets-selected-by-user

**Step 4**: eventbrite system processes the ticket order as specified in the api call (along with price/discount, qty, eventId, etc.) on eventbrite.com site

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Jatin

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the widget altogether and post directly to the EB checkout page.

For example:

```
<form action="http://www.eventbrite.co.uk/orderstart?ebtv=C" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="eid" value="[EVENT_ID]">
    <input type="text" name="quant_[TICKET_ID]_None" value="[QUANTITY]" />
    <input type="text" name="discount" value="[DISCOUNT_CODE]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="has_javascript" value="1">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I wouldn't have thought this method is officially supported but it seems to work at the moment.